# Indext is missing a QuerySet. Define indext.model, indext.queryset - django

Tags: django

I tried to see another questions of people, and I didn't got an answer.
There is my view and my url reference to the view:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Album

class indext(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'showname/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'albums'
    def albums(self):
        return Album.objects.all()
```

and my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.indext.as_view(),  name='index'),]
```

Everything is set well.. why does it gives me that problem?

And since I'm already asking, I have another question related:
Why django made "render\httpresponse\loader" if they edventually make generic view that makes the all work for you? Why they have didn't just do generic view?

Comment: Dont define `albums`, but `model` or `queryset`.

Comment: But why? In this tutorial he did differently?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3yB0_4Yd48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what to do: define a `model` or `queryset` attribute on your class. You have neither, but you do have an irrelevant `albums` method. Remove that and just have:

```
class indext(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'showname/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'albums'
    model = Album     # or queryset = Album.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thank you. it works. but in the next tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3yB0_4Yd48 he did another way and it works to him although.. so what is the purpose of the function he enter into the class at the video? and why for him it worked?

Comment: He doesn't define an `albums` method though, he defines `get_queryset`. That's an alternative to defining the `queryset` object directly but usually you'd only use it when you wanted to do some more complex filtering, eg restrict the albums to ones owned by the current user.

Comment: So if i do "model = Albums" its like sending to the page the set of the albums (Album.ojects.all())? and if yes, so how for example can i sen a number of values to the same pgae? (eg Album, Song)

Comment: i clear my question - when i do "model = Album" what happening behind the scence?

Comment: You can look at the code, but the default implementation of `get_queryset` looks for a model or queryset attribute; if it finds a model it will call its default manager, ie `objects.all()`.

Comment: daniel, its will be ok to get your skype\whatsapp?